# Why do I get an endless loop from my code?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    int num; 
    int square;
    int sum;

    while (num) {
        if (num > 0) {
            scanf("%d", &num);
            square = num * num;
            sum = square + sum; 
            printf("%d          \n", sum);
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

I'm trying to produce the sum of squares for positive numbers, and when the first negative number is inputted, the loop ends. Result needs to be left justified by 10 spaces.

Comment: negative numbers are considered true in C. So your loop will only end if `num`  is 0. The easy way to fix would be to repeat the test you have in your `if`  in the condition of the `while`

Comment: You don't initialize `num`.

Comment: Use of uninitialized vars: num.

Comment: not to mention, num isn't initialized the first time...

Comment: why can't you just debug such a simple program?

Comment: You need a real condition for your `while` loop (like `num >=0` if you want it to stop for negative values). Besides, I'd personnaly use a `do {...} while(num >= 0)` for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Pseudo code: 1. set num to 0, 2. scanf num, 3. if num is negative quit loop. 4. sqare num, 5. add to sum, 6. goto 2.

Answer (score 2):

The code has undefined behavior: the first time you test the value of `num`, it is uninitialized.  If by chance it happens to not be negative, you scan a new value and add its square to uninitialized variable `sum`, producing more undefined behavior, it the value input was negative, the next test fails and the loop repeats forever.

Left justifying in a 10 space width is obtained with the `%-10d` conversion format.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num, square, sum = 0;

    while (scanf("%d", &num) == 1 && num != 0) {
        square = num * num;
        sum = square + sum; 
        printf("%-10d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want the number to be **right** justified in a 10 space width so all output values align properly, use the `%10d` format instead.

If you input large numbers or too many items, you will eventually exceed the range of type `int`. You can try and increase the range of variables `square` and `sum` by making them `long long int` or even as commented by PeterJ `unsigned long long int`, and allow for larger values to be computed:

```
int main(void) {
    int num; 
    unsigned long long square, sum = 0;

    while (scanf("%d", &num) == 1 && num != 0) {
        square = (long long)num * num;
        sum = square + sum; 
        printf("%21llu\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `(long long)num * num` will be converted to `unsigned long long` that has a range at least as large in the positive values.

Comment: Thanks, but when I type [2, 2, -2] my answer should be nothing, however it gives me 12

Comment: @Eric: why should it be nothing? 2*2 + 2*2 + (-2)*(-2) = 12 as expected...

Comment: I've figured that out, but if the number at the end is larger than 10 or more digits, the result turns negative

Comment: @Eric start from the good C book. Basics - how numbers are stored, what is 2 complementary etc etc. BTW the question you ask was answered here at least 10 in the last 7 days

Comment: @Eric: when the number gets *too large*, there is an arithmetic overflow, which is undefined behavior, and on most current architectures results in a wrap around at 2^31 into very large negative values.You can increase the range of `square` and `sum` by making these `long long int` but the problem will still occur when you exceed the range of that type.

Comment: Make square and sum the `unsigned long long` as square is never negative

Comment: @PeterJ: yes, for an extra bit of range, as posted.

Answer (score 0):

Using uninitialized variable leads to undefined behavior.You are using uninitialized local variable `num` in your while loop. `num` can have any value in it. If the value is smaller than 0 the loop will run forever. It will also loop for ever if the value smaller than 0 is entered using `scanf`.

For undefined behavior please check lines from standard
6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that
>   could have been declared with the register storage class (never had
>   its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared
>   with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior
>   to use), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: _Non-static variables (local variables) are indeterminate. Reading them prior results in undefined behavior._ I still dont get why would somebody DV this answer?

Comment: You should mention that it has UB as i wrote in first comment. Yes, they could at least write comment.

Comment: It is not the issue. The only undefined behaviour here is if the num is 0 (as it is random and can have any value as it is uninitialized) and it will not enter the loop at all.

Comment: "*If the value is greater than 0 the loop will run forever.*" <- not if the user enters `0`. Anything else you write is correct, but not the (only) reason for the OPs problem, so it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @PeterJ And if you dont know if its going to enter `while` or not is defined behavior?

Comment: and the implied test is `num != 0` not `num > 0` since the explicit  test is simply `num`

Comment: @Filip Kočica Your comment is quite difficult to understand. If by the chance num is equal zero before entering the while loop, the statements inside the loop will never execute.

Comment: @PeterJ what? Irrespective of what value it has, it is UB because you cannot read uninitialised values. And BTW it is not random, it is indeterminate. Random would be unspecified.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya No, you can read an unitilaised value without any problems (except dereferencing the pointers). The problem is that the read value is unpredictable, so it can be zero as well.

Comment: @PeterJ 6.3.2.1p2:

If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya because it contains garbage. I afraid you do not understand what you cite.

Comment: @PeterJ do you understand trap representations? Do you understand registers having special unitialized state which is not a valid representation in the domain of the type? I am afraid you don't. Stop claiming others don't understand things you think you understand and __read__.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya please provide me a trap representation for the `int`. Actually I can only imagine nowadays only one case is the 'NAN'. Except floats there are no trap representations on ARM, AVR, PIC & x86 machines

Comment: @PeterJ I have asked that if you dont know if program will enter the `while` loop, then its `defined behaviour` ? i dont think so. This program has undefined behavior. Due to reading indeterminate and due to you dont know if program will enter while loop or not.

Comment: @PeterJ the C standard doesn't state that `int` should use 2s compliment representation. For any system that uses 1s compliment, all 1s is a trap representation. 1s compliment has been used in many real systems for a long time.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya do you have less eccentric examples? I would say something younger than 40-50 years? And please do not write about Univac computrs

Comment: `int num; ... while (num) {` is UB.   It makes no difference if an `int` has a trap value or not.  It makes no difference if `int` is 2's complement or not.   It is still UB.  A compiler can take advantage of OP's weak code.

Comment: @PeterJ The CDC Cyber 18 used the 1s complement. And it was used in the 80s. Again, it is not about what what is commonly used. It is what about the standard says. Since the standard says it is UB, a compiler could make assumptions which would also break the behaviour on modern X86 or ARM processors.

Comment: @chux I did not say that is not an UB!!!!!. I just pointed that it may even do not enter the loop!!!!

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya no you told about the trap representation so I have asked if you know any on computers are used mowadays? Please give me any example on x86, ARM, AVR or PIC, SPARC exept the `NaN`. Maybe appollo calculator had some - but it does not matter now

Comment: @Peter J Do you agree irrespective of  value the behavior of OP's code is UB per standard?

Comment: @PeterJ I already told you once, I'm telling you again in the hope you finally take care: You're arguing **a lot** with concrete behavior on some platform, which is *not helpful at all* for programming in C. Please understand the concept of the *abstract machine* and also what *undefined behavior* means.

Comment: @MCG This might have been lost in the huge discussion here: Looking at the code and the result described by the OP, although you're correct about the UB, this isn't the *immediate* problem. Spotting and explaining the UB should be **part** of any answer, but IMHO it isn't an answer in itself.

Comment: @MCG I am afraid, not being able to determine whether a loop will enter or not is not Undefined Behavior but Indeterminate. You cannot determine anything about the loop even in `int x; scanf("%d", &x"); while(x) { ... } `, but that doesn't make it UB. Same goes for loops on `random()`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya although unlikely, you pointed out yourself that an uninitialized `int` *could* contain a *trap representation*. So yes, the code *does* have UB :) In practice, you typically avoid both anyways .. *indeterminate* isn't much better than UB. Note that random is again something different, your typical random function gives you guarantees about the distribution.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oh yes yes, I am saying that it is UB. I was just replying to - *And if you dont know if its going to enter while or not is defined behavior?* There is UB, but for different reasons.

Comment: @Ajay And that reason is variable is uninitialized.

Answer (score -2):

I hope, this might help ending the loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
int num = 0; 
int sum = 0;

while (num >= 0) {     
     scanf("%d", &num);
   if (num>=0) {
     sum = ( num * num ) + sum; 
     printf("          %d\n", sum);
   }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @FelixPalmen In the original code, the loop will not over. In my code, if the input number is less than zero then the loop will break. In original code, only if you put zero as input then the loop will over.

Comment: You use `num` uninitialized, just like the original code.

Comment: Actually there no condition is required like that. You can just let 5==5 as condition of the loop. Like `while (5==5)` and no need to initialize `num`

Comment: `num` could be 0, then your program doesn't do anything. `num` could be a trap representation, then your program does *whatever "random" action* (*undefined behavior*)

Comment: OK. I think now its fixed. I changed the loop condition.

Comment: `break` is still ugly (what's wrong with `int num = 1; while (num>0)`?) and not checking the return value of `scanf()` still leads to bugs, try entering something that's not a number.

Comment: The if condition is necessary after the scanf. Cause, if I input a negative number it will still calculate the value. And if I put a not character it will calculate using ASCII value. That is not my concern.

Comment: No it won't... try it

Comment: `%d` expects a number. If the input doesn't contain a number, nothing is read, `num` stays untouched and `scanf()` returns 0.